# How To create a Simple NDK Program in Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

Hi I am new to android Programming and NDK.Yet i am not clear with working in NDK.I just downloaded android ndk r4.If i want to develop appln using NDK,and i refered

http://marakana.com/forums/android/android_examples/49.html

for reference,But still not clear how to create the header file and implementation,I did nt have any previuos exp in c language.And they asked for run javah tool to create the JNI header file.

I dont know how to use javah tool,but i found it in java bin directory and i tried using cmd

```
javah -jni com.sarmal.MyLib
```

It shows as  `class file not found`,

Hello Guys,when i list the folders and files,it is shown,this is the [Image](http://www.filefactory.com/file/b21c48d/n/Error.JPG)

What could be the problem?

What's requirement of Cygwin here?

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the `hello-jni` example code that comes with the NDK for guidance.

Comment: Use this to setup your eclipse to auto compile your C code and then refresh the project.  http://www.rbgrn.net/content/348-get-your-eclipse-integrated-ndk-on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to compile the java application first, using "ant compile", so the java classes will be created and javah can export the java header file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble earlier, but this solved it:
javah -classpath [wherever you compiled HelloWorld] -o HelloWorld.h example.jni.HelloWorld

Got it from http://www.inonit.com/cygwin/jni/helloWorld/header.html

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to the source directory of the .java file
and then execute the `javah -jni sourcefile.java`
it will create the header file